# Quantum System with Only One Energy Level

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, temperature, entropy

Is it possible for a quantum system to have a maximum energy level. And, is it possible for that maximum energy to also be equal to the ground energy?

Let's assuming such a system can exist. What would it's temperature be? There doesn't seem to be any change in entropy and neither internal energy. So $dS/dU$ is $0/0$, so is the temperature undefined?

If such a system could be built on a macro scale, would we be able to directly observe and interact quantum effects at room temperature?

Comment: How would you possibly interact with this system? It obviously can't absorb, emit, or transfer energy of any kind, so what are you going to do that will allow you to observe or interact with it?

Comment: It gravitates. A little. :)

Comment: Does interacting with it require a change in it's internal energy? Do particles in a quantum computer interact, yet they all remain at ground energy?

Comment: I think this like asking what the temperature of a lone particle would be. It doesn't have one.

Comment: Here's a guess at how you might interact with it. I'm not sure if this system is the same as a hypothetical atom which only allows electrons in the ground state. If for example, if such a material was connected to electron source, like a wire to a battery, it wouldn't let electrons into it unless the internal energy in the material didn't change. One electron goes it, one comes out, both at same energy level. If an electron is too high of an energy level, it won't be able to enter the material. If there are no electrons available outside the material to swap with, no electrons will leave it.

Comment: So it seems this material is always in equilibrium with whather it's touching, whether that other thing is something very hot or something very cold. I'm wondering if particles in the material would be immune to noise which would destroy quantum behavior for the purpose of quantum computation.